# Execute single cucumber test case in a scenario outline using command line command

Tags: protractor, bdd, webdriver-io, cucumberjs

I want to execute single test case from a scenario outline using protractor.For example in the below Scenario Outline if I want to execute the test case TCID0002 alone, how I can run the test case TCID0002 using protractor?

```
@shopping
Scenario Outline: Test
    Given the user navigates to xxx.com
    When the user searches for <product>
    Then the current page is shopping cart page
    Examples:
    |TCID    |  product|
    |TCID0001|soap     |
    |TCID0002|watch    |
    |TCID0003|lipstick |
```

To run all the test case now I use

```
protractor Config.js --cucumberOpts.tags="@shopping"
```

Is there any command to execute single test case in the scenario outline ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution to execute single test case in cucumber with a help of my team member.

To run single test case follow the below 2 steps

**Step 1**

Keep **TCID** in the scenario title as shown below

```
Scenario Outline: <TCID> test case to validate search
    Given the user navigates to xxx.com
    When the user searches for <product>
    Then the current page is search result page
    Examples:
    |TCID    |  product|
    |TCID0001|soap     |
    |TCID0002|watch    |
    |TCID0003|lipstick |
```

**Step 2**

Use cucumberOpts.name in your command. 'cucumberOpts.name' will filter the scenarios which contain the given string in the scenario title. 
--cucumberOpts.name="WAGCAR0002" will filter the WAGCAR0002 scenario alone.

**Command**

The below command will execute the test case 'WAGCAR0002'

```
protractor Config/wagConfig.js --cucumberOpts.name="WAGCAR0002"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use tags on the examples table and splitting it into two tables. Then provide the `@runone` tag to tags option of `cucumberOpts` in config file.

```
@runall
Examples:
    |TCID    |  product|
    |TCID0001|soap     |
    |TCID0002|watch    |
    |TCID0003|lipstick |

@runone
Examples:
    |TCID    |  product|
    |TCID0002|watch    |
```

Comment: - as per your answer each time when I want to execute a single test case from a sceanrio outline I have to build the examples as shown above. I am looksing for a command line command to execute a single test case from sceanrio outline.

Comment: Found solution for this ! it may help you